# minimum variance estimator for $\mu^2/\sigma^2$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, parameter-estimation

I'm trying to do the following exercise

> Let $(X_1,...,X_n)$ be a random sample from an $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ distribution with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ unknown. Assuming $n>3$, find a minimum variance unbiased estimator for $\mu^2/\sigma^2$.

I think I need to find an unbiased estimator $g$ for $\mu^2/\sigma^2$ and then compute the conditional expectation $E(g| \sum x_i, \sum x_i^2)$.  At the moment I'm not sure even how to write down the preliminary estimator.

Comment: I don't see how your $g$ can be unbiased for $\mu^2/\sigma^2.$ The denominator can sometimes be very small. With $\mu = 50, \sigma=5$ six of your estimators according to the first displayed equation were 36.53635, 49.06081, 1067.28662, 3235.78078,   85.11678, and 8860.74075 while $\mu^2/\sigma^2 = 100.$ Are you sure you wrote what you intended?

Comment: @BruceET oh yeah, you're right - what I wrote makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the LLN, the fraction $\theta^*=\frac{\left(\overline X\right)^2}{S^2}$ is a consistent estimate for $\theta=\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2}$. Here 
$$S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum \left(X_i-\overline X\right)^2=\frac{n}{n-1}\left(\overline {X^2}-\left(\overline X\right)^2\right).$$

Let us find bias of this estimate: $\overline X$ and $S^2$ are independent, $$\overline X \sim N\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right) \text{ and } \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{n-1}.
$$ 
Note also that $$\mathbb E\left[\frac{1}{\chi^2_{n-1}}\right]=\frac{1}{n-3}$$

Therefore
$$
\mathbb E[\theta^*]=\mathbb E\left[\frac{\bigl(\overline X\bigr)^2}{S^2}\right] = \mathbb E\left[\bigl(\overline X\bigr)^2\right]\cdot \mathbb E\left[\frac{1}{\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}}\right]\cdot\frac{n-1}{\sigma^2}
$$
$$
=\left(\mu^2+\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{n-3}\cdot\frac{n-1}{\sigma^2} = \frac{n-1}{n-3}\left(\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2}+\frac1n\right).
$$
Therefore $$\theta^{**}=\frac{n-3}{n-1}\theta^*-\frac1n$$
is the unbiased estimate for $\theta=\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2}$.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm new to this subject so some of the notation is unfamiliar to me. for instance, what does $\sim$ and $\chi_{n-1}$ mean in this context?

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity,  is it important to know that $\theta^\ast$ is *consistent*? Or did you just mention it in passing?

Comment: @Plinytheill The notation $\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$ means that the inderlying r.v. has chi-square distributed with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. 
Your question was: how to find an unbiased estimate for the first step? The consistent esimate can help to determine how can this estimate looks like.

Comment: ok thanks again. this will take me a little while to go through.

Comment: finally finished verifying everything. it took me a very long time to find a satisfactory proof that the sample variance is distributed in that way: the only proof I could find used the fact that moment generating function determines distribution and the proof of that took me to the theory of holomorphic functions and facts about Fourier inversion!  anyway, thanks again.

Comment: This is the fundamental fact in statistics of normal samples. If follows from Cochran's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem#Sample_mean_and_sample_variance with the help of Basu theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu%27s_theorem#Independence_of_sample_mean_and_sample_variance_of_a_normal_distribution_(known_variance)